# How to render Emoji on HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following string:

```
\ud83d\udc51 CODE :: davon top\n\ud83d\udc51 MATERIAL :: spandek rayon\n\ud83d\udc51 PRICE :: 70.000\n\nFIX ORDER langsung hubungi contact :\n\ud83d\udc49 LINE : hijabroom\n\ud83d\udc49 PIN BB : 28EFA80B\nRead mekanisme before order!\n\n
```

And I wanted to render it like the following:

[image: Desired Emoji HTML Rendering of String Above]

How can I do so?

Comment: This might help: http://timwhitlock.info/blog/2013/03/emoji-on-the-web/

Comment: Please see [this](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode) and [this](http://www.busydoingnothing.co.uk/emoji.html)

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you should create associative array with keys equal to all your Emojis (as Unicode sequences) and corresponding values equal to links to images representing definite emoji. Then you only have to replace Emoji-codes by images (using regular expressions, for example)